# beta regression (betareg) with caret and train

Tags: r, regression, r-caret, beta

I have a dataset with a dependent in range (0,1) and numerical/categorical predictors. Chiefly to streamline the code and easily accomplish cross validation (feature selection/model fitting), I would like to use `betareg` with `caret`. I thought the model would be something like:

```
library <- "betareg"
type <- "Regression"
loop <- NULL
fit <- betareg.fit(x, y, z = NULL, weights = NULL, offset = NULL,
                  link = "logit", link.phi = "log", type = "ML", 
                  control = betareg.control())
predict <- predict(object, newdata = NULL,
                   type = c("response", 
                            "link", "precision", "variance", "quantile"),
                   na.action = na.pass, at = 0.5)
```

`parameters` and `grid` don't seem to be relevant in this case?!

So, How off am I?

On a different note, would it be possible to do stepwise beta regression?

Plenty Appreciated

Comment: This belongs in [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks, gets blurry ... is it because it is an R question?

Comment: No, because it's a statistics question about beta regression. And the people over there knows more R and more statistics :)

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman I disagree, as this is about implementing stepwise beta regression.